# Updating a listbox in wxpython?

Tags: python, wxpython

I am having some trouble, updating a listbox, Ive tried Refresh and Update but those returned errors.

The listbox uses a list to get its information. It will show the initial items in the list.

However when i update the list (while the program is running), it will not show the changes live.

If you have difficulty understanding what I mean, please comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the method `Set()`:

```
self.mylistbox.Set(listofchoices)
```

> Resets the list box to the list given in choices—that is, the current
>   elements are removed from the list and replaced by the new list.